# change "output format" of pgfkeys sci or fixed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath

I have defined an environment that is used for calculation as shown below

```
\newcounter{Precision}
\newenvironment{calc}[1][1]{\setcounter{Precision}{#1}
$\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
}
{ 
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=\thePrecision]{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}$}
```

The following environment call will help in setting the required precision.

```
\begin{calc}[2]
  \pgfmathparse{5/(2^(15))}
\end{calc}
```

In the similar way, I want to change the output format from "sci" to "fixed" through the argument.

```
\begin{calc}[2, fixed]
  \pgfmathparse{5/(2^(15))}
\end{calc}
\begin{calc}[2, sci]
  \pgfmathparse{5/(2^(15))}
\end{calc}
```

How to redefine the key in the newenvironment ?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete MWE in which you also show how you use the environment? Naively I would say `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` but this is most likely no the answer you are looking for, so please add the MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an environment for this. Just make a new command as a shortcutwith a default argument for the printing style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand*{\myparse}[2][sci,precision=2]{%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber[#1]{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
}
\begin{document}
\myparse{5/(2^(15))},
\myparse[fixed, precision=5]{5/(2^(15))},
\myparse[1000 sep=\|, precision=0]{2^15)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi percusse, Thanks for the code.How to replace the Dot symbol with X

Comment: @Narashimaraja You can add `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/sci generic={mantissa sep=\times, exponent={10^{#1}}}}` at your preamble to change all occurences.